# Verizon FiOS - what's involved with getting Internet and TV to my home?

Tags: fios

I know the cable and telco already have lines that run into apartment buildings. How does Verizon FiOS get their service to our home? From this diagram, it looks like [Verizon provides an ethernet jack](http://www.verizon.com/support/residential/internet/fiosinternet/networking/setup/vz9100em/124133.htm). Are they running fiber up to a certain point, then running CAT5/CAT6 for the "last mile"?

I tried looking up specifics on how the infrastructure is built, but could not find any details.

Comment: This might be enlightening: http://www.bricklin.com/fiosinstall.htm They run fiber to a box on the side of your house, which converts it to ethernet (similar to the modem for DSL or Cable).

Comment: I don't know if this varies by area or level of service or new vs. pre-existing.  In our area, they run fiber to an external interface, then coax to outlets in the house.  The router is the only place with Ethernet connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They run a new Fiber line into your house, install an Optical Network Terminal.

[image: ONT]

See this nice video Verizon put together: [Wiring Your Home for FiOS - Verizon](http://www.verizon.com/Support/Residential/Quick-Guides/Wiring-For-FiOS.htm).

If you want the most accurate answer, I'd advise picking up the phone and calling Verizon, and asking them what their current solution involves for people in your circumstance.